# Looking for repurposed drugs database

Tags: medical, bibliography

I'm a MSc student and my thesis is probably going to be about repurposed drugs. But I can't seem to find any sort of database about already repurposed drugs, or any drugs that are undergoing clinical trials (this one is more important), except a cancer database. Truth to be told, I want to work in something other than cancer, but if that's not an option,. I'll take a cancer database as well. Does anyone have any links, or tips? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLUE REPURPOSING HUB is a hub for articles and other diverse information about repurposed drugs. At [CLUE REPURPOSING](https://clue.io/repurposing-app) , you can get details like clinical phase, disease area, target, vendor etc. Please let me know, if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very useful!! I hope I get the hang of it soon.

Comment: Manyak, if you find it is as correct answer please mark it as accepted. [See here] (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow#:~:text=Click%20the%20green%20outlined%20checkmark%20to%20the%20left,yourself%20describing%20the%20solution%2C%20and%20then%20accept%20that.). It will help other members of community to identify useful answers.